# Error when trying to transfer files from GCP to AWS

Tags: google-cloud-platform

So I am running this

```
gsutil -m cp -r gs://<some-gcp-bucket>/* s3://<s3-bucket>
```

to try and transfer data from GCP to AWS.

So it works for some files (none of the files are actually that big themselves but they all total around 900 Mb), but then other files I am getting a

`broken pipe` error

and

`Invalid read during daisy chain operation, got data of size 8192, expected size 6455`

this error as well. I've looked at the forums and it told me to lower the multi-threading params and I did, but to no avail. I'm kind of lost as what to try next.

Comment: Hi there. What version are you running? Can you please share the output for the command `gsutil version`

Comment: @ArmandoCuevas `gsutil version: 4.51`

Comment: I think a better approach for this very specific case is to open a request directly with Google at [Report Issues and Request Features with Issue Trackers](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers) or at [Github](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gsutil/issues)

Comment: I have the same issue, did you solve it?

Comment: @Vojtěch I did actually! So it ended up using their key file. Firstly, I did `gcloud auth activate-service-account --key-file <key-file>` first.

Then `aws configure`, put in your AWS creds (secret access key, access key id)

Lastly, `gsutil cp -r gs://<google cloud item> s3://<s3 bucket>`

Hope this helps!